# Adding boundary thickness parameter to the given circle code

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry, thickness

I have this code that creates an image containing a circle. Now I want to add a boundary thickness parameter in the given code just like we can do in [openCV](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-draw-a-circle-in-Python-OpenCV.php).

Please help me with how can I add that to the given code.

**Code:**

```py
from datetime import datetime

from random import randint

from PIL import Image


def circle(data, center, radius, color, size):

    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if (x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2 <= radius ** 2:
                data[x * size  + y ] = color
    return data


def main():

    start_time = datetime.now()
    size = 400
    circle_centre = (int(size/2), int(size/2))
    circle_radius = circle_centre[0]
    circle_color = (0, 0, 0) 
    data = [(255, 255, 255)] * size ** 2  
    img = Image.new('RGB',(size,size),'white')

    data = circle(data, circle_centre , circle_radius , circle_color, size)
    img.putdata(data)
    img.show()
    img.save("circle.png", "PNG")
    print(f"Time needed: {datetime.now() - start_time}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I guess you could draw two circles, first a larger one in one color, then a slightly smaller one in the other color. This will leave the edge of the circle in the first color. The difference in radii would be the thickness of that border.

Comment: your circle function... only fill the pixel if the distance of that pixel to the origin is *between* the two radii (inner, outer).

Comment: repost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585970/how-to-draw-a-circle-in-python-without-using-circle-function-from-any-library