# How to draw a circle in python without using circle function from any library?

Tags: python, geometry

I am trying to draw a circle in python without using any circle function by using the following inputs parameters

Inputs:

- Radius of the circle in pixel: r
- Thickness of the circle in pixel: d
- Center of the circle in pixel coordinate: x, y
- Size of the image in pixel: h, w

I have written this code to draw a circle. Is there any other efficient way to do this?

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint
from PIL import Image

def circle(data, center, radius, color, size):
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if (x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2 <= radius ** 2:
                data[x * size  + y ] = color
    return data


def main():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    size = 400
    circle_amount = 2
    circle_centre = (int(size/2), int(size/2))
    circle_radius = circle_centre[0]
    circle_color = (0, 0, 0) 
    data = [(255, 255, 255)] * size ** 2  
    img = Image.new('RGB',(size,size),'white')
    for i in range(circle_amount):
        data = circle(data, circle_centre, circle_radius, circle_color, size)
        circle_radius = int(circle_radius/1.1)
        circle_color = (255, 255, 255)
    img.putdata(data)
    img.show()
    img.save("circle.png", "PNG")
    print(f"Time needed: {datetime.now() - start_time}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [I've seen this question before, very recently. why repost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73575717/adding-boundary-thickness-parameter-to-the-given-circle-code)

Comment: Thickness problem has been resolved, thanks to you and Cris Luengo, now I am trying to find an efficient way to draw a circle by different method.